# How can I have a subdomain point to a specific port on 1&1 VPS account

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, subdomain, rewrite, 1and1

Does anyone know how I could setup my 1&1(host) Virtual Private Server account to have sub-domain that points to a specific port on a Windows Server 2008?

So I want http://{something}.{site}.com   to be setup to open port 9999 on my webserver at {site}.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with DNS but you can use a simple redirect.
just redirect http://{something}.{site}.com  to  {site}.com:9999
Your VPS probably has a control panel that allow you do do this.

Comment: I need the same to do, but my VPS doesn't has a control panel like Plesk. Can you explain how to do it otherwise?